# Virtual Host getting forbidden error message on Mac OS

Tags: laravel, macos, apache2, virtualhost

I am working on Laravel project on Mac OS and trying to create Virtual Host for the project.

I have run the following command on terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and add below code and saved:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxxxxxx.com
    ServerAlias www.xxxxxxx.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxxxxx/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

After I have run this command: **sudo nano /etc/hosts** and **127.0.0.1       xxxxxxx.com** and saved interminal.

But when I open **xxxxxxx.com** I am getting this message in the browser:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Can someone guide me why I am not able to see the Laravel project? I am doing for the first time so It would be great If you guide me.

Thnaks.

Comment: Do you have the `.htaccess` file into your `./public` directory?

What happens if you open `xxxxxxx.com/index.php` ?

Comment: Yes. I have .htaccess file in public dir. When I open with http://xxxxxxx.com/index.php I am getting same error. Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

Comment: @Mr.Happy I have the same issue.  Have you managed to solve it?  How?